# java.lang.IllegalStateException error when showing dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Just received two "Crashes & ANRs" on the app store developer console containing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1354)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1372)
```

I have logically found the error: I have an async call back which is used to make and HTTP request. If I click on the button which makes the HTTP call and then click back (i.e., close the activity), I receive this issue.

Here is the code which causes the issue:

```
    ResponseErrorHandler errHdl = new ResponseErrorHandler();
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = errHdl.HandelError(error, responseBody);
    FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    dialogFragment.show(fragMan, TAG + "ErrorDialog");
```

So if I correctly understand what is happening is that my activity is closing, and then the dialog fragment is trying to show the dialog when the activity is gone.

I do cancel my network request when the activity ends:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Network.cancelRequests(ConnectingActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: I believe [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) will clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the activity [is being closed/killed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) before showing the dialog and act accordingly.

E.g.:

```
if (!parentActivity.isFinishing()) {
    dialogFragment.show(fragMan, TAG + "ErrorDialog");
}
```

Hope this helps.